# Create an Options page with two image upload fields

Tags: theme-options

I’d like to build a simple and clean Options page with two upload fields and a preview of the uploaded images. I tried a lot of frameworks like [NHP](https://github.com/leemason/NHP-Theme-Options-Framework) and [UpThemes](http://liftux.github.com/UpThemes-Framework/) but they are way to heavy for my purpose (e.g. I don’t need several options tabs).

I found [this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-integrate-the-wordpress-media-uploader-in-theme-and-plugin-options/) which fits to my needs but I don’t know how to add a second upload field. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
function wptuts_get_default_options() {
    $options = array(
        'logo' => ''
    );
    return $options;
}


function wptuts_options_init() {
     $wptuts_options = get_option( 'theme_wptuts_options' );

     // Are our options saved in the DB?
     if ( false === $wptuts_options ) {
          // If not, we'll save our default options
          $wptuts_options = wptuts_get_default_options();
          add_option( 'theme_wptuts_options', $wptuts_options );
     } 
     // In other case we don't need to update the DB
}
// Initialize Theme options
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wptuts_options_init' );


function wptuts_options_setup() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ('media-upload.php' == $pagenow || 'async-upload.php' == $pagenow) {
        // Now we'll replace the 'Insert into Post Button inside Thickbox' 
        add_filter( 'gettext', 'replace_thickbox_text' , 1, 2 );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wptuts_options_setup' );


function replace_thickbox_text($translated_text, $text ) {  
    if ( 'Insert into Post' == $text ) {
        $referer = strpos( wp_get_referer(), 'wptuts-settings' );
        if ( $referer != '' ) {
            return __('I want this to be my logo!', 'wptuts' );
        }
    }
    return $translated_text;
}


// Add "Options" link to the "Appearance" menu
function wptuts_menu_options() {
    //add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
     add_theme_page('WPTuts Options', 'Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'wptuts-settings', 'wptuts_admin_options_page');
}
// Load the Admin Options page
add_action('admin_menu', 'wptuts_menu_options');


function wptuts_admin_options_page() {
    ?>
        <div class="wrap">

            <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"><br /></div>

            <h2><?php _e( 'Options', 'wptuts' ); ?></h2>

            <!-- If we have any error by submiting the form, they will appear here -->
            <?php settings_errors( 'wptuts-settings-errors' ); ?>

            <form id="form-wptuts-options" action="options.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <?php
                    settings_fields('theme_wptuts_options');
                    do_settings_sections('wptuts');
                ?>

                <p class="submit">
                    <input name="theme_wptuts_options[submit]" id="submit_options_form" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Settings', 'wptuts'); ?>" />
                    <input name="theme_wptuts_options[reset]" type="submit" class="button-secondary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Reset Defaults', 'wptuts'); ?>" />        
                </p>

            </form>

        </div>
    <?php
}

function wptuts_options_validate( $input ) {
    $default_options = wptuts_get_default_options();
    $valid_input = $default_options;

    $wptuts_options = get_option('theme_wptuts_options');

    $submit = ! empty($input['submit']) ? true : false;
    $reset = ! empty($input['reset']) ? true : false;
    $delete_logo = ! empty($input['delete_logo']) ? true : false;

    if ( $submit ) {
        if ( $wptuts_options['logo'] != $input['logo']  && $wptuts_options['logo'] != '' )
            delete_image( $wptuts_options['logo'] );

        $valid_input['logo'] = $input['logo'];
    }
    elseif ( $reset ) {
        delete_image( $wptuts_options['logo'] );
        $valid_input['logo'] = $default_options['logo'];
    }
    elseif ( $delete_logo ) {
        delete_image( $wptuts_options['logo'] );
        $valid_input['logo'] = '';
    }

    return $valid_input;
}


function delete_image( $image_url ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // We need to get the image's meta ID..
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts where guid = '" . esc_url($image_url) . "' AND post_type = 'attachment'";  
    $results = $wpdb -> get_results($query);

    // And delete them (if more than one attachment is in the Library
    foreach ( $results as $row ) {
        wp_delete_attachment( $row -> ID );
    }   
}


// JavaScript
function wptuts_options_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'wptuts-upload', get_template_directory_uri() .'/wptuts-options/js/wptuts-upload.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox') );  

    if ( 'appearance_page_wptuts-settings' == get_current_screen() -> id ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
        wp_enqueue_script('wptuts-upload');

    }

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_options_enqueue_scripts');


function wptuts_options_settings_init() {
    register_setting( 'theme_wptuts_options', 'theme_wptuts_options', 'wptuts_options_validate' );

    // Add a form section for the Logo
    add_settings_section('wptuts_settings_header', __( 'Logo Options', 'wptuts' ), 'wptuts_settings_header_text', 'wptuts');

    // Add Logo uploader
    add_settings_field('wptuts_setting_logo',  __( 'Logo', 'wptuts' ), 'wptuts_setting_logo', 'wptuts', 'wptuts_settings_header');

    // Add Current Image Preview 
    add_settings_field('wptuts_setting_logo_preview',  __( 'Logo Preview', 'wptuts' ), 'wptuts_setting_logo_preview', 'wptuts', 'wptuts_settings_header');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wptuts_options_settings_init' );

function wptuts_setting_logo_preview() {
    $wptuts_options = get_option( 'theme_wptuts_options' );  ?>
    <div id="upload_logo_preview" style="min-height: 100px;">
        <img style="max-width:100%;" src="<?php echo esc_url( $wptuts_options['logo'] ); ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php
}


function wptuts_settings_header_text() {
    ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Manage Logo Options', 'wptuts' ); ?></p>
    <?php
}


function wptuts_setting_logo() {
    $wptuts_options = get_option( 'theme_wptuts_options' );
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="logo_url" name="theme_wptuts_options[logo]" value="<?php echo esc_url( $wptuts_options['logo'] ); ?>" />
        <input id="upload_logo_button" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Upload Logo', 'wptuts' ); ?>" />
        <?php if ( '' != $wptuts_options['logo'] ): ?>
            <input id="delete_logo_button" name="theme_wptuts_options[delete_logo]" type="submit" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Delete Logo', 'wptuts' ); ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Upload an image.', 'wptuts' ); ?></span>
    <?php
}
?>
```